# Edition of polygon with hole disappears with high zoom level

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

As the title says, I'm having a little problem with polygon edition at high zoom level.

I'm using the Google map API to create a polygon with a hole in it. That allows me to "highlight" a zone on the map. In my app, the user can modify that polygon so that it perfectly matches its zone.

Everything works fine for the edition but, at the 2 highest zoom levels, the edition "points" disappear. That makes edition a bit hard if you really want to be precise when drawing the zone.

Is there some parameter I'm missing to make the edition "points" appear at every zoom levels?

I have a working jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/nrtvewgh/1/

Here is the code:

```
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  center: {lat: 50.383074874246, lng: 5.1561069488525},
  zoom: 12,
  mapTypeId: 'satellite'
});

var WORLD_COORDS = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(-85.1054596961173, -180),
    new google.maps.LatLng(85.1054596961173, -180),
    new google.maps.LatLng(85.1054596961173, 180),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-85.1054596961173, 180),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-85.1054596961173, 0)
];

var zoneCoords = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(50.414233409894, 5.1438760757446),
    new google.maps.LatLng(50.408462829958, 5.1216888427734),
    new google.maps.LatLng(50.383074874246, 5.1561069488525),
    new google.maps.LatLng(50.408435479564, 5.164647102356),
    new google.maps.LatLng(50.413348040727, 5.151150226593)
];
console.log(zoneCoords);
var domainZone = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: [WORLD_COORDS, zoneCoords],
    strokeColor: '#FFFFFF',
    strokeOpacity: 0.9,
    strokeWeight: 4,
    fillColor: '#FFFFFF',
    fillOpacity: 0.2,
    zIndex: 0
});
domainZone.setMap(map);
domainZone.setEditable(true);
```

Just zoom on the "points" at the edge of the zone and they will eventually disappear.

I noticed I can still drag the edge of the zone at the last 2 zoom levels, but this is not intuitive at all.

I have looked for answers but can't seem to find people that have the same problem.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: I tried your Fiddle and it does show the behavior you've said - but only in Chrome 56.  I tried Firefox 52.0.2 and IE 11 and those show the dots down to all zoom levels.  This was on Windows 7.

Comment: Indeed this does not occur in IE 11 (and probably not on Firefox as well, not tested that one yet).

However, I was in a meeting with my client yesterday and he showed me the behavior on Chrome on his Mac book (iOS). My god things get even worse! 
The map controls (zoom in, out, ...) randomly disappear based on the zoom level and he even looses his app session when that occurs (I don't even know how that's possible). He was not happy at all and I can understand it.

I'm currently working on a dirty workaround to get things working as fast as possible.

Thanks for the note!

Answer (score 1):

For those who come across the same issue, I have found a dirty workaround that seems to work.

Instead of a single polygon with a hole, I created two polygons.

- That same one with a hole in it and with a strokeOpacity of 0.
- Another simple polygon that has the same coordinates with a fillOpacity of 0 and a higher zIndex.

When the user wants to edit the holed polygon, the trick is to make him edit the  regular polygon behind the scenes. Whenever the simple polygon changes, I simply synchronize the holed polygon so that it looks exactly the same.

When editing a regular polygon, I don't have this zoom problem and everything is working fine.

I hope this answer is clear enough. Don't hesitate to ask if it is not. I might even be able to make a jsfiddle is someone needs an example.